# Canvas разных потоков

Tags: canvas, java

У меня в одном потоке всё время происходит отрисовка объекта Canvas, который является полем класса этого потока. Как извлечь изображение из этого Canvas и поместить его на другой Canvas в другом потоке?

Comment: Покажите, как вы рисуете на канве? Вы сами создаете или вам приходит в методе. Просто некоторые вещи от этого зависят.

Comment: @Andreich, канва первого потока создана программно, а второй поток передаётся из SurfaceView методом lockCanvas();

Comment: ну я бы отрисовал данные с первой канвы на битмап и потом этот битмап кинул в другой поток

Comment: @Andreich, я так и хотел. Почему-то возвращает пустой битмап.